# Bind ngx time picker to form control in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I got a few working Angular material date pickers, but no time pickers. The version is Angular 8.

Since Angular material does not offer a time picker, I am using the [ngx-material-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker).

I can add the time picker to the html, but I don't know how to get the selected time since the binding it to an input throws an error:

```
  <input [ngxTimepicker]="timePicker" />
  <ngx-timepicker-field
          #timePicker
          [format]="24"
          [defaultTime]="'6:00 am'"
   ></ngx-timepicker-field>
```

The error is `ERROR TypeError: "this._timepicker.registerInput is not a function."`

I tried with a form field as well, but receive the same error:

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <input
            matInput
            [formControl]="timeFormCtrl"
            [ngxTimepicker]="timePicker"
          />

          <ngx-timepicker-field
            #timePicker
            [format]="24"
            [defaultTime]="'6:00 am'"
          ></ngx-timepicker-field>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What is your angular version ?

Comment: Angular 8. I'll add the info to the question.

Comment: why is your element tag not ngx-material-timepicker ?

Comment: I'm using the timepicker field, you can find the documentation [here.](https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/)

Comment: Based on the document, the **directive**  ngxTimepicker  you use here:  <input [ngxTimepicker]="timePicker" /> accept the component instance of "NgxMaterialTimepickerComponent". You passed instance "NgxTimepickerFieldComponent",  so it is not working. `<ngx-material-timepicker #timePicker></ngx-material-timepicker>` should work.

Comment: Do you got  solution for it

Comment: @HD I did make it work. I will post an answer shortly, hold on...

Comment: @HD.. See my answer, maybe it can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61770922/6892466

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work in the end, but without the `ngx-timepicker-field`. I decided to use a normal `ngx-timepicker`.

Here's what the template looks like:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Time</mat-label>
    <input
        matInput
        aria-label="default time"
        [ngxTimepicker]="defaultValue"
        [value]="'0:00 am'"
        [(ngModel)]="time"
     />
     <ngx-material-timepicker #defaultValue>
     </ngx-material-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

As you can see, I am not using a form control, but simple `[(ngModel)]` binding to a variable called `time` in my controller.

```
export class FeatureListComponent implements OnInit {
// [...]
    time = '6:00 am'; // this shows up as default time.
```

Now, the time picker looks like this, which is not exactly what I wanted, but it's good enough for now:

[image: What the time picker form field looks like]

[image: Selected time picker with the standard clock layout]

Thanks to all the suggestions. I'm not sure why the time control field did not work in the end.

Comment: Is there any solution for ngx-timepicker-field

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know, since I have not worked with this time picker since I made the post.

Comment: @Nancy Someone posted a possible solution below, but without much context.

Answer (score 0):

@Nancy

Here is how to get values from working ngx-timepicker-field:

html part:

```html
<ngx-timepicker-field 
    [format]="24" 
    [defaultTime]="'08:00'" 
    (timeChanged)="addTimeA($event)">
</ngx-timepicker-field>
```

ts part:

```js
import { NgxMaterialTimepickerToggleIconDirective } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';

addTimeA(event: NgxMaterialTimepickerToggleIconDirective) {
  this.service.timepickerA = event.toString();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your solution lacks more context, especially what `this.service` refers to.